# try-catch против if-else

Tags: c#, исключения, try-catch

Я сейчас изучаю *C#* по учебнику Шилдта, а он учит заключать все узкие моменты в `try`-`catch`.

Это нормальная практика ветвления кода, или лучше пользоваться `if`-`else`? Я, конечно, понимаю разницу между ошибками и исключениями. Но теперь у меня расплывается граница между некоторыми исключениями и обычными ветвлениями в коде.

Например операция деления одного числа на другое подразумевает, что пользователь может (попробовать) поделить число на ноль. С одной стороны результат этой операции будет исключением, которое можно обработать. С другой стороны можно и не доводить дело до исключения, заранее проверяя вводимые числа.

Как принято поступать в обществе профессиональных программистов?

Comment: Для начала, не стоит читать Шилдта. Он известен ужасным качеством книг и отвратительными советами. Почитайте лучше Albahari.

Comment: См. также http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/558472/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Вообще подмена исключений условными блоками - не самая здравая идея. Любая функция (метод) в принципе должна выполнять одну возложенную на нее задачу. Если по тем или иным причинам задача выполнена быть не может, то должно быть брошено исключение. Сам метод в общем случае не должен заниматься обработкой собственных исключений, для этого есть вызывающий его код. Метод должен либо выполнить задачу, либо сообщить о невозможности ее выполнения. Вернемся к вашему примеру:

> Например операция деления одного числа
> на другое подразумевает, что
> пользователь может (попробовать)
> поделить число на ноль. С одной
> стороны результат этой операции будет
> исключением, которое можно обработать.
> С другой стороны можно и не доводить
> дело до исключения, заранее проверяя
> вводимые числа.

В этом случае должно быть именно вызвано исключение - ваш метод получил некорректные входные данные, и не может правильно произвести операцию деления. Тут интересна такая ваша фраза:

> С другой стороны можно и не доводить
> дело до исключения, заранее проверяя
> вводимые числа.

Можно. Но  что должен делать код дальше, если проверка не прошла? Вернуть некое магическое значение типа -1 или 0? Это будет некорректно с точки зрения логики. Вывести сообщение об ошибке? Это будет попахивать ошибкой проектирования - отвечать за вывод сообщений об ошибках должен совсем другой код. Появится связность  кода, а это очень плохо.

Помимо того, существуют такие исключительные ситуации, в которых никакие if-else не помогут. Скажем, не удалось открыть соединение базой данных. Что программа должна делать дальше? Войти в условие и попытаться еще раз открыть его, а затем еще, еще и еще? Вряд ли.

Ну а что касается if-else, то их имеет смысл использовать там, где "не сработавший" вариант - всего лишь одно из возможных корректных состояний программы.

Резюмирую - метод должен либо выполнить задачу, либо сообщить о невозмождности ее выполнения. Обрабатывать собственные исключения чаще всего не нужно. Следует пробрасывать их вверх.

Весьма рекомендую также прочесть у Рихтера главу, посвященную исключениям. Да и вообще [саму эту книгу](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/21236101/)

Comment: я глянул оглавление книги, и мне показалось, что она для тех, кто уже разбирается в C#? Эдакий LVL up?

Comment: ну вообще да, она не для начального изучения языка

Comment: Ясно. Тогда сейчас дочитаю Шилдта, а потом приступлю к Рихтеру.  
У меня уже сложилось некоторое представление о том, как НЕ надо программировать, так что Шилдт будущего программиста во мне убить не сможет, как бы он не старался :)

Comment: @teanЫЧ слова о том, что по Шилдту ни в коем случае нельзя учиться, были сказаны не мной)

Comment: Да я просто пытался выдать шутку юмора.  
По всем учебникам мнения расходятся. Кому-то нравится автор, кому-то не нравится.

Answer (score 9):

Нет, я не согласен с Шилдтом.

Обычно код структурируется таким образом, что:

- Большинство операций имеют право выбросить исключение. Они не ловят исключения вызываемого кода, кроме редких случаев, где это действительно нужно.
- Если у вас происходит ручное управление ресурсами, вам скорее всего пригодится try/finally, а не try/catch
- try/catch оборачивает как можно большие, внешние блоки программной логики. Например, итерацию главного цикла.

По поводу того, где использовать исключения, а где if/else: если операция может ожидаемо завершиться неудачей, используйте ветвление. Если операция завершается неудачно лишь в исключительных случаях, используйте исключения.

Пример: если пользователь ввёл текст в editbox, вы не можете исходить из того, что он ввёл число. Используйте такой код:

```
if (int.TryParse(s, out value))
    return value;
else // покажите message box и не закрывайте диалог
```

В случае, если значение читается из конфигурационного файла, нечисловое значение там, где ожидается число — серьёзная проблема, и код соответственно меняется:

```
return int.Parse(s); // если там не число, бросаем исключение, которое
                     // будет поймано на верхнем уровне операцией чтения конфигурации
```

Дополнительное чтение по теме: http://www.artima.com/intv/handcuffs.html

Comment: В голове давненько в бекграунде крутится вопрос (в принципе, и на отдельный вопрос потянул бы, а ещё принципиальней можно и в гугле поискать). 

Так вот - вы из wcf-сервисов выбрасываете исключения или возвращаете что-то вроде OperationResult<T>?

Comment: @Veikedo: я сам не писал WCF-сервисы, поэтому сказать не могу. Но если там возможно выбросить исключение, я бы так и сделал.

Answer (score 3):

Ветвление - это нормальное поведение программы. Исключения указывают на потенциальную деформацию логической целостности некой модели, от чего ее нужно спасать (закрывать соединения, прекращать работу с объектом и т.п.).

Вот в C++ как вы и сказали, исключения добавлены как вспомогательный не обязательный механизм. Но try-catch зачастую читается куда лучше, чем хитроумный контроль за валидностью объекта по многим критериям, специальным переменным.

Comment: Как уже указал коллега ветвление - это нормальное поведение программы. Исключения = ошибки программы. Хотел бы добавить что очень тяжело учесть все варианты для ветвления. Механизм try - catch может ловить неучтенные варианты. К тому же этот механизм дает возможность использовать конструкцию finally{}, которая, несмотря на исключение, выполнит необходимый кусок кода в любом случае. (например закроет подключение к БД)
P.S. 2Free_ze - интересный у тебя ник )))

Comment: @Freezze, "Исключения = ошибки программы".  
Очень жаль, что вы так думаете. http://habrahabr.ru/post/130597/

Comment: "Но try-catch зачастую читается куда лучше".  
Я тоже так думаю. Ведь, порой, чтобы не увешивать код макаронными проверками на всевозможные значения, проще заключить все в try-catch.

Comment: @teanЫЧ
В первозданном виде исключения - это именно ошибки. Ошибочные ситуации на уровне _логики_ программы, а не технические, вроде деления на ноль, переполнения стека, выхода за пределы буфера и т.п. (хотя C# по их случаю тоже любит делиться инстансами специальных типов). Хотя, никто не запрещает использовать исключения для ветвления, но читал я где-то, что от большого количества обрабатываемых исключений проседает перформанс.

@Freezze
И тебе привет, давно потерянных интернет-брат =)

Comment: @teanЫЧ Я не очень верно выразился, согласен. Исключения - это не ошибки. Исключения включают в себя ошибки. Так будет более верно.