# Передача исключений и логирование

Tags: c#

Не так давно я поднял тему [исключений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/299080/c-try-cathe-vs-if-else).
Потом я задал вопрос про [пробрасывание исключений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/320615/c-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9), и там разговор зашел о логировании, в связи с чем я эту тему и поднимаю.

В этом вопросе я просто излагаю свои мысли и привожу в пример свой текущий, маленький, обучающий проект, и прошу Вас сказать мне, где я ошибаюсь.  Так что вопроса, как такового, здесь нет. Есть только призыв к обсуждению и критике. И так многа букав:

---

Почитал msdn и прочие источники, где наткнулся на различные стратегии обработки исключений. Меня заинтересовали:

1. "передача исключения в исключение-оболочку для сохранения содержимого и создание нового исключения. Этот подход является реализацией шаблона трансляции исключений"
2. "регистрация исключения в журнале"

Пункт 1 это и есть тот проброс исключений, о котором я [спрашивал ранее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/320615/c-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9). А пункт 2 это то, на что меня натолкнули товарищи [@VladD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10105/vladd) и [@DreamChild](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10162/dreamchild) (за что им и спасибо). Сегодня я покопался во всем этом и вот, что получилось:

Предположим, есть у нас метод, который выполняет запрос и заполняет датасет:

```
    public bool Open_SQL(string query, string table)
    {
        try
        {
            query = "select * from asd";
            if (dataSet.Tables.Count > 0)
                _dataSet.Tables.Clear();
            SqlCommand sqlComand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlconnection);
            sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = sqlComand;
            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(_dataSet, table);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Ошибка при попытке выполнить Sql запрос: " + query, e);
        }
    }
```

Метод этот будет у нас находиться в самом низу *пищевой цепочки*, и чтобы путь исключения был долгим, ошибку создадим именно в нем, подменив валидный запрос на `"query = "select * from asd";"` (таблицы asd нет, так что ошибка 100%). Этот метод вызывается из другого объекта (не буду расписывать метод полностью, а отражу самую суть):

```
    // Подключение DataGrid к данным
    public bool ConnectDataGrid()
    {
        try
        {   
            ...
            if (sqlClient.Open_SQL(query, tableName))
            {
                 ...
            }
            ...
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Ошибка при подключении набора данных к DataGridView", e);
        }
    }
```

А этот метод в свою очередь вызывается из объекта на более высоком уровне. Да, архитектура приложения получилась многоуровневой, так как мне показалось это удобным, ибо у каждого объекта есть свой круг/уровень объектов с которыми он может взаимодействовать. Поэтому в критических ситуациях, когда работа приложения не может быть продолжена (например ошибка подключения к базе данных при старте), может выстроиться цепочка из 3-4 зависимых исключений.

---

На это закончим описание исключений, и перейдем к модулю логирования. А тут я написал маленький класс:

```
static public class uNix_Logger
{      
    static private void Read_and_writeToFile_Exception(Exception e, string logFile)
    {
        if (e.InnerException != null)
        {
            Read_and_writeToFile_Exception(e.InnerException, logFile);
        }

        StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter(logFile, true);
        stream.WriteLine("Ошибка: " + e.Message);
        stream.WriteLine("Объект: " + e.Source);
        stream.WriteLine("Метод, вызвавший исключение: " + e.TargetSite);
        stream.WriteLine("Стэк: " + e.StackTrace);
        stream.WriteLine("====================================");
        stream.Close();
    }

    static public void CreateLog(Exception e)
    {
        if(!Directory.Exists(uNix_Const.errorLogPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(uNix_Const.errorLogPath);
        }

        string logFile = string.Format(uNix_Const.error_template, DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace(":", "."));
        Read_and_writeToFile_Exception(e, uNix_Const.errorLogPath + logFile);
    }
}
```

Класс простенький и все что он делает - это создает директорию и файлы в которые рекурсивно записывает информацию об ошибках. Да, в таком виде он не очень практичен, так как в стек может попасть критически важная информация, которую бы нам не очень хотелось показывать. Но экранирование исключений это тема для отдельного вопроса...  Но а наш класс вполне способен составить простой лог следующего вида (я не стал тут писать данные стэка, так как много места занимают):

```
Ошибка: Недопустимое имя объекта "asd".
Объект: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
Метод, вызвавший исключение: Void OnError(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException, Boolean, System.Action`1[System.Action])
Стэк:    ...
====================================
Ошибка: Ошибка при попытке выполнить Sql запрос: select * from asd
Объект: Nix_Manager
Метод, вызвавший исключение: Boolean Open_SQL(System.String, System.String)
Стэк:    ...
====================================
Ошибка: Ошибка при подключении набора данных к DataGridView
Объект: Nix_Manager
Метод, вызвавший исключение: Boolean ConnectDataGrid()
Стэк:    ...
====================================
Ошибка: Ошибка начальной инициализации компонентов
Объект: Nix_Manager
Метод, вызвавший исключение: Void .ctor(System.String[])
Стэк:    ...
====================================
```

Такой лог позволяет мне увидеть, что именно произошло, в каком месте, и что этому предшествовало. А пользователю показывается простое человекопонятное: "Ошибка! Продолжение работы программы невозможно! Попробуйте перезапустить её."

Comment: >Класс простенький и все что он делает - это создает директорию и файлы в которые рекурсивно записывает информацию об ошибках. Да, в таком виде он не очень практичен, так как в стек может попасть критически важная информация, которую бы нам не очень хотелось показывать

не очень хотелось бы показывать кому?

Comment: @teanЫЧ, а если

    Directory.CreateDirectory(uNix_Const.errorLogPath);

неудачно (ну, допустим, прав не хватает), то все рухнет?

А если в ходе выполнения программы возникнет несколько ошибок и время существенно сдвинется -- то начинанаете писать в новый файл -- не запутаетесь?

Что призойдет если несколько экземпляров программы одновременно начнут логгинг?

Comment: Не хотелось бы показывать любому желающему. Ведь в логе может содержаться конфиденциальная информация, которую не стоит показывать посторонним. Или я не прав?

Comment: Ну да, так и надо. Stack trace разработчикам, понятное сообщение юзеру.

Comment: @avp, я понимаю, что модуль логирования сам может рухнуть, но я просто хотел акцентировать внимание именно на проблеме исключений и логирования, опуская все остальные неточности в коде. Прошу меня за это не винить.

Comment: @avp: Если исключение ожидаемо ([exogenous](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx)), то его необходимо поймать в нужном месте и обработать. Завершать выполнение нужно только если пришло непредусмотренное исключение.

---

@teanЫЧ: лог можно и зашифровать, в конце-концов. Открытый ключ у программы, закрытый у разработчиков :-)

---
@avp: Есть готовые системы (наподобие того же `log4*`), которые решают такие проблемы на корню.

Comment: >Не хотелось бы показывать любому желающему. Ведь в логе может содержаться конфиденциальная информация, которую не стоит показывать посторонним. Или я не прав?

логи вы пишете не для пользователя, а для разработчика, чтобы он мог разобраться в причинах возникновения исключения и понять, где и при каких условиях оно произошло. Априори подразумевается, что единственным, кто будет читать эти логи, окажется тот человек, которому их не просто можно, а даже нужно показывать

Comment: И все же, одновременный вызов

    Read_and_writeToFile_Exception

из разных экземпляров программы может привести к перемешиванию сообщений в логе?

@teanЫЧ, это все вопросы не для меня, а для Вас, для лучшего понимания границ применимости своей проги.

Comment: @avp: ну, если в сообщение добавляется ID экземпляра программы и timestamp, можно потом отфильтровать. Но по-хорошему надо, конечно, вынести логирование в отдельный процесс. У винды есть для этого системный лог, у линукса тоже наверняка что-то есть.

Comment: @VladD, боюсь, что не всегда. Я, правда не знаю, как StreamWriter реализован в шарпе (в \*nix, судя по всему), но если это `FILE *`, открытый на append, то данные, выводимые write() (по заполнению буфера потока (4K)) могут перемешаться. 

К счастью, файлы, открытые с append разделяют общий указатель позиции записи. Поэтому последующий вывод не запишется поверх более раннего из другого процесса. Но, вывод длинного трейса может оборваться на полуслове и продолжиться (не потеряв ни байта) после куска чужого лога.

Наверное, если уж заводить *классы*, то стоит позаботиться о локинге.

Comment: @avp из разных экземпляров программы может привести к перемешиванию сообщений в логе?  
Пользователь при запуске программы логинится. Мне в любом случае придется отслеживать, чтобы один пользователь не мог в один момент времени зайти в базу дважды. Значит мне можно будет писать логи для разных пользователей, и разбрасывать по разным папкам. Тогда логи не смешаются.  

-  
Плюс, скорее всего, надо будет сделать логирование асинхронным, чтобы в случае возникновения нескольких ошибок в один момент не было сбоев никаких.

Comment: @teanЫЧ, а как же принципы универсальности и повторного использования, которыми хвалиться ООП? 

Лучше посмотрите, на что-нибудь типа syslog для \*nix.

Comment: В любом случае, доставка залогированного сообщения в файл — подробности. В зависимости от различных требований (многопоточность, anyone? много процессов? много хостов?) детали имплементации могут отличаться. Сторонники ООП могут абстрагироваться от конкретной имплементации за интерфейсом.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class Msg
{
    public static void MessageInfo(string caption, string msg)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(msg, caption, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }

    public static void MessageError(string caption, string msg)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(msg, caption, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

    public static void MessageError(Exception _ex, string caption)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(_ex.Message, caption, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        WriteLog(_ex.Message + "\n************************\n" + _ex.StackTrace + "\n******************\n\n");
    }

    public static void ShowError(Exception _ex, string caption)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(_ex.Message, caption, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

    public static void ShowError(string txt, string caption)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(txt, caption, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

    public static DialogResult MessageQuery(string caption, string msg)
    {
        return MessageBox.Show(msg, caption, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
    }

    public static void WriteLog(string msg)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(msg)) return;
        string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\log.txt";
        using (var outfile = new StreamWriter(path, true, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            outfile.WriteLine("***********************");
            outfile.WriteLine("дата: {0}", DateTime.Now);
            outfile.WriteLine();
            outfile.Write(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Вызов:
где-то там, где угодно..

```
private void boxDiam_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (boxDiam.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                bindSteel1.Filter = "DIAMETR_BL = " + boxDiam.SelectedValue.ToString();
                bindSteel2.Filter = "DIAMETR_BL = " + boxDiam.SelectedValue.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                bindSteel1.Filter = "";
                bindSteel2.Filter = "";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Msg.MessageError(ex, this.Text);
        }
    }
```

1. Появится окно в ошибкой и запишется в лог.
2. Можно использовать тихий режим - без вывода ошибки, или только ошибка без записи в лог

Comment: мне кажется, что следует разделить класс Msg на два: один выкидывает сообщения пользователю, второй пишет логи.

Comment: Меня устаревает, это из рабочего проекта.
Писать логи - это по сути приватный метод этого класса, тут он публичный просто по тому публичный, потому что.. забил :) так что, нет смысла делать отдельный класс, возможно, как наследуемый от, например, TLog (где бы были реализованы методы записи и чтения) в виде protected.  
А зачем передавать? можно по цепочке вести обработку и вывести в конце.