# Что использовать правильней: if(), или try-catch?

Tags: исключения, любой-язык, try-catch

Например что использовать, когда нужно создавать колонку в таблице только в том случае, если такой колонки в ней нет?

Я могу, как написать код, который будет проверять, существует ли колонка, и лишь потом добавлять без ошибок, так могу и без проверки пытаться добавить колонку, обернув метод в `try-catch` (`если есть` — *перехватится исключение*; `если нет` — *колонка добавится*).

Результат работы будет одинаковым.

И таких примеров можно привести массу, например можно проверять файлы на существование, и только потом делать копирование, а можно перехватывать исключения.

Какой метод **более** грамотный, или правильный?

Comment: По возможности, исключений лучше избегать. Они предназначены для *исключительных* ситуаций.

Comment: @DmitryD. вот только такая возможность есть далеко не всегда...

Comment: @DmitryD., "избегать исключений" - это можно понять по-разному. Знавал я таких программистов, которые, следуя этому принципу ни разу за свою карьеру не написали строчки кода, генерирущей исключения.

Comment: Классическая статья по теме: [Vexing exceptions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/).

Comment: См. также http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/299080/

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как проверить существование файла?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/414593/23044)

Comment: @jfs зачем вы добавляете эти странные метки?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ  попробуйте погуглить их, если не узнаёте, а потом прочтите заголовок вопроса. Связь станет понятной.

Comment: @jfs погуглить? Тут это не принято просить. За такое обычно тревогу даже можно схлопотать. Если бы метки существовали, или хотя бы как минимум имели описание здесь на сайте (а не в "погуглить"), то разговор был бы другой. В текущем виде они не уместны.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ метки не для этого существуют. Говорите за себя только.

Comment: @jfs к тому же, зачем это делать в вопросе 3-годичной давности?

Comment: @Suvitruf if vs. try/catch это и есть lbyl vs. eafp

Comment: @jfs я боюсь, что людей, которые это поймут, единицы. К тому же, уже стоит метка [tag:try-catch]. Она охватывает всю тему.

Comment: @Suvitruf тем кто знают что это (и хотят поделиться знаниями), эти метки помогут ответ на соответствующие вопросы добавить. Тем кто не знает что это (и хотят узнать), эти метки помогут соответствующие вопросы найти.

Comment: Предлагаемые метки не характеризизуют тему, скорее -- сложность вопроса. Под неё можно подвести практически любую тему и любой язык программирования. Категорически против создания таких меток. Предлагаю: модератор убирает метки с вопроса, участники перестают устраивать войну правок и идут на мету, выснять что делать с метками. По итогам двухнедельного обсуждения консенсусное решение будет применено к этому вопросу/метке, и при необходимости к другим.

Comment: @jfs я не вижу особой поддержки со стороны сообщества по этим правкам (откат ваши правок другими участниками говорит как раз об обратном). На данный момент я откатываю сообщение к оригинальному виду. Если вы считаете, что добавление меток, которые понятны лишь единицам и которые охватывают слишком большой спектр вопросов (что нивелирует их полезность), действительно улучшили бы вопрос, то предлагаю вам поднять обсуждение данного вопроса на [мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) и посмотреть, что скажут другие участники.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Исключения позволяют сделать код чище и понятнее, поскольку с их помощью можно *разделить* выполнение действий и обработку ошибок. В книге Мартина «Чистый код» этот аспект описан самым первым.

При этом, по моему опыту, надо именно *разделять* код: выносить блок `try`/`catch` в отдельный метод. Программист, который будет разбираться с вашей программой, скажет вам «спасибо». Эта конструкция весьма громоздка, даже в простой форме `try`/`finally`, и в середине большого метода озадачит кого угодно.

Второй плюс исключений в том, что они позволяют передавать дополнительную информацию. Функция `atoi` из C ничего не могла сказать о том, почему именно не удалось конвертировать строку в целое число.

```
int result;
result = atoi("123"); /* в result 123 */
. . .
result = atoi("foo"); /* что в result? */
```

В таких языках, как Java и C# вы можете добавить в свой класс исключений необходимые свойства, сочетая какие-нибудь *коды ошибок* с *контекстами вызова* и *ещё чем-нибудь*. Пример:

```
. . .
catch (SqlException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ошибка '{2}' в строке {0} процедуры {1}", e.LineNumber, e.Procedure, e.Message);
}
. . .
```

Разработчики, которые давно и прочно перешли на исключения, делают свой код ещё чище, не возвращая никаких кодов ошибок, в частности, пресловутого **null**:

```
// Что будет, если в хранилище нет пользователя с указанным userid?
// Вернёт null или сгенерирует исключение?
User user = userRepository.GetById(userId);
```

В настоящее время считается, что правильнее создавать исключение (за аргументами снова отсылаю к книге «Чистый код»). Если метод используется для проверки наличия пользователя, его рекомендуют переделать в форму `TryX`. Она неуклюжа, но уже привычна, по крайней мере, для программистов .NET:

```
User user;
if (userRepository.TryGetById(userId, out user))
{
    . . .
}
```

Что более ценно, она однозначна: смотря на код, вы не думаете: «а что, если такого пользователя нет?»

Теперь посмотрим на ситуацию с другой стороны — а когда *не надо* использовать исключения? На мой взгляд, тогда, когда они затрудняют понимание кода. Если ситуация *не исключительная*, тогда в тексте программы должна быть обычная проверка.

Например, приложение для нового документа генерирует имена **Untitled.foo**, **Untitled1.foo**, **Untitled2.foo** и т.д.

Та ситуация, что файл с таким именем уже существует, является вполне обычной, не исключительной, поэтому и реализовать код корректнее с помощью обычной проверки:

```
public string GetNewDocumentName(string prefix)
{
    var filename = prefix + ".foo";

    if (!File.Exists(filename))
        return filename;

    int suffix = 0;
    do
    {
      filename = prefix + (++suffix).ToString() + ".foo";
    } while (File.Exists(filename));

    return filename;
}
```

Этот код не только быстрее, чем аналогичный с использованием исключений, но, что важнее, понятнее другим программистам, потому что неявно передаёт им дополнительную информацию: эта штука будет случаться регулярно, и мы к этому готовы.

А вот, например, невероятная ситуация, что в папке скопилось 2 миллиарда untitled-файлов — несомненное исключение.

```
public string GetNewDocumentName(string prefix)
{
    var filename = prefix + ".foo";

    if (!File.Exists(filename))
        return filename;

    int suffix = 0;
    do
    {
      if (suffix == int.MaxValue)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("You're crazy!");

      filename = prefix + (++suffix).ToString() + ".foo";
    } while (File.Exists(filename));

    return filename;
}
```

Такой код выглядит более запутанным. К счастью, мы можем часть проверок возложить на компилятор C#:

```
public string GetNewDocumentName(string prefix)
{
    var filename = prefix + ".foo";

    if (!File.Exists(filename))
        return filename;

    int suffix = 0;
    do checked
    {
      filename = prefix + (suffix++).ToString() + ".foo";
    } while (File.Exists(filename));

    return filename;
}
```

Откуда возникает ещё одно правило: код можно сделать чище, если знать язык, платформу, библиотеку, и опираться на их исключения.

Выше я написал, что исключения выполняются медленнее, чем проверки, и хочу уточнить свою мысль: не надо опираться на производительность при принятии решения. Правильная передача смысла другому программисту, чистота кода — то, к чему следует стремится. Разница в производительности, хотя и существует, никогда не была настолько большой, чтобы пользователи её замечали. Ну, если только вы не пишите код для самого вложенного цикла в каком-нибудь графическом движке.

Answer (score 31):

Предварительная проверка быстрее работает и зачастую является более точной. Но только обработка исключений дает полную гарантию.

Пример: простое создание файла. Ошибок тут возможно - море:

- в имени могут быть запрещенные символы (набор разрешенных символов зависит от файловой системы!);
- полный путь к файлу может оказаться слишком длинным;
- файл мог быть уже создан;
- может не быть доступа для создания файлов;
- диск может быть защищен от записи или вообще не поддерживать ее (CD-ROM тому пример).

Все эти варианты можно проверить заранее - и выдать пользователю понятное сообщение на русском языке.

Но есть ситуации, которые ни одна предварительная проверка не отловит:

- файл может быть создан другой программой сразу после проверки;
- файл может быть заблокирован антивирусом;
- если файл создается на сетевом ресурсе - может "отвалиться" сеть.

Comment: А имеет вообще смысл делать 5 проверок(Возьмем ваш пример), когда можно проделать 1 действие и словить исключение? Меньше кода получается.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Да, имеет - проверка может пройти быстрее, чем попытка создания файла. Плюс, вовремя проваленная проверка может отменить сложное действие (скажем, подготовку данных для сохранения в файл). Но, как правило, проще ловить исключение.

Comment: @iluxa1810 на мой взгляд, нужна разумная комбинация проверок, для прерывания выполнения алгоритма когда и так ясно что дальше делать ничего не стоит, и отлова исключений, для всех остальных случаев

Comment: @iluxa1810 Вы полагаете, что у вас не будет пяти разных catch на разные исключения (валить всё в одно!), а если будут -- то обрабатываться будут одинаково?