# Обработка ошибок и возврат значения из функции C#

Tags: c#

задался вопросом, а все таки как же "правильно" отлавливать ошибки в функции точней как правильно возвращать результат выполнения функции , если в процессе произошла ошибка.

Например:
Есть форма на ней datagirdview и и кнопка button1

Задача по нажатию кнопки  заполнять datagirdview например названием регионов России и индексом из rest сервиса .
[54,"Новосибирск"]

Для удобности я создаю отдельный файл класса и всю "математику" стараюсь держать там, соответственно я изолирован от работы непосредственно с контролами формы в основном потоке.

Создаем функцию которая отправляет запрос на rest и в идеале должна получить ответ в json и вернуть список List с нужной нам инфой

```
class Regions{
public string id{get;set}
public string title{get;set}
}

public static List<Regions> GetRegions(){
try{
WebRequest link = WebRequest.Create(@"link")
....

}
```

Далее получаем ответ, создаем экз. класса, парсим json,заполняем его и возвращаем.

А теперь сам вопрос:
Если по како то причине при запросе возникнет ошибка тогда мне нужно вернуть пустой экземпляр класса либо заполнить его с учетом ошибки.На самой форме тогда тоже придется это проверять.

Как правильно и красиво реализовать эту проверку?

Comment: Обычно я руководствуюсь правилом - если метод может выполнить свою работу - он должен её выполнить, если метод не может сделать то, для чего предназначен - он должен создать исключение. Таким образом пустую коллекцию точно не надо возвращать. [Подробнее об исключениях](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/exception-throwing)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/558472/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-if-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-try-catch

Comment: Не стоит использовать статический метод. Его нужно сделать экземплярным и вынести в другой класс, назначение которого - именно получение данных. А этот класс переименовать в `Region` - единственное число. Свойства назвать `Id` и `Title` - с большой буквы. [Framework Design Guidelines](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/) - советую ознакомиться с правилами именования и т. п.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Не бойтесь исключений.

Исключения следует применять, когда возникает ошибка, обработка которой лежит вне ответственности класса. То есть у вас есть функция, которая должна вернуть результат, а ошибка вообще не позволяет определить этот результат. В этом случае кидаете исключение и не заботитесь о том, что возвращать. Ошибка - это не пустой результат, а именно ошибка, и вам в любом случае обрабатывать ее не в этом классе, а на верхнем уровне.

Вариантов у вас два:

- Не ловить исключение.
- Поймать исключение и бросить свое, передав пойманное в качестве параметра:

```
catch (SomeException e) {
    throw new MyCustomException("Результат не получен по такой-то причине.", e);
}
```

Comment: Честно никогда не пользовался этим, пищу для размышлений хорошую дали , спасибо

Answer (score 3):

вы можете попробовать создать класс, описывающий результат выполнения метода, и вместо `public static List<Regions> GetRegions(){//code}` использовать `public static Response GetRegions(){//code}`

Пример Response:

```
public class Response
{
  public bool rStatus {get; set;} // признак выполнения (true - успех, false - провал)
  public List<Regions> Data {get; set;} // результат выполнения
  public string srvMessage {get;set;}
}
```

и на самой форме проверить Response.rStatus

Comment: Отличная идея!  Как я сам не догадался )  спасибо

Comment: Был рад помочь, спасибо :)

Answer (score 1):

```
class Regions
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }

        public static List<Regions> GetRegions()
        {
            List<Regions> regionsList = new List<Regions>(); 
            try
            {



                WebRequest link = WebRequest.Create(@"link");


                //заполняем список   regionsList полученым запросом
                //...
                //...
                //...
                //...
                return regionsList;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message,@"Ошибка",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);//показываем что произошла ошибка
                return new List<Regions>(); //возвращаем пустой список
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: MessageBox.Show(e.Message,@"Ошибка",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error); Не получиться , этот код выполняется в другом потоке

Comment: Но как не странно если подключить Windows.Forms  и  выполнить MessageBox  ошибки не выдает , так что это как вариант. Не совсем корректный но вариант

Comment: `MessageBox` следует убрать. Не должен класс, назначение которого - получение данных, быть приколоченным гвоздями к GUI WinForms. Таким образом этот класс становится невозможно использовать, если проект будет переписан на WPF, Xamarin или вообще web.