# "If {} else {}" или "try {} catch() {}" C#

Tags: c#

Столкнулся с вопросом использования условной конструкции или перехвата исключения. Читал информацию, что "try {} catch() {}" потребляет больше ресурсов, чем условная конструкция.

Я пишу код, в котором проверяется введенный в textBox путь к файлу. И у меня есть два варианта:

1. Условная конструкция и вывод сообщения через messageBox;
2. Перехват исключения сообственного класса и вывод сообщения через messageBox;

Какая разница в данном случае? При перехвате исключения я могу вывести информацию об объекте его вызвавшем или еще, что-то, что мне будет нужно. Тем не менеее, существуют обе конструкции, так что и когда лучше использовать? Если я правильно понимаю - это вопрос предпочтений, но ведь есть какие-то общие правила. В интернете читал информацию, но так и не понял до конца разници.

Где-то было написано, что исключения позволяют обрабатывать ошибки, а не просто их "выявлять", но мне показалось такое объяснение довольно абстрактним. Хотелось бы понять разницу.

Comment: что-то мне кажется, если в принципе в голове такая мысль рождается, то вряд ли это исключительная ситуация в коде.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/558472/Что-использовать-правильней-if-или-try-catch

Comment: Если Вы заранее рассматриваете потенциальную возможность ввода ошибочного пути, т.е. воспринимаете эту ситуацию как штатную, вряд ли возникновение этой ситуации во время исполнения следует считать ошибкой и обрабатывать как исключение... imho

Comment: Почитал, спасибо.