# throw и try-catch - что это и зачем нужно?

Tags: c++, try-catch, throw

из лекций в вузе поняла, что блок `try-catch` нужен для отлавливания исключений, но так ли это? И зачем тогда `throw`? Почему нельзя использовать простую обработку исключений?
Зачем они нужны, если можно спокойно найти ошибку дебаггером и использовать обработку исключений?

Comment: *"нужен для отлавливания исключений"* Да. *"зачем тогда throw"* Он вызывает ("бросает") исключение, которое можно поймать `catch`. Они работают в паре. *"использовать обработку исключений?"* Что вы под этим имеете в в виду? `catch` нужен чтобы программа не падала при исключении, а могла как-то его переварить и продолжить работать.

Comment: вообще хороший ответ есть тут -> https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/558472/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9-if-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-try-catch?rq=1

Comment: Под _"использовать обработку исключений?"_ я имела ввиду использование тех же if. К примеру когда идет вычисление 1/х, где х изменяется в цикле, то ведь можно обойтись простым if при х=0, и смысл этого блока отпадает. Можете, пожалуйста, привести пример, где этот блок необходим и его нельзя ничем заменить?

Comment: @Первачок, я буквально таки дал ссылку сообщением выше, там есть практические почемучки

Comment: Простите, а ***как именно*** поступить при том же обнаружении деления на 0?  Прекратить выполнение программы? Вернуть какое-то значение (и как его отличить от обычного возвращаемого значения)? Так вы планируете обработку в том месте, где возникла ситуация. И как какая-то библиотечная функция N-ой вложенности может знать, как обработать исключение **правильно**? А если возвращать какой-то признак ошибки — значит, *все* функции по стеку вызовов должны содержать свой обработчик ошибок. Можно, но дорого и неудобно...

Comment: Исключения не используются для ошибок кода в программе. Они используются для обработки ошибок во время выполнения программы, которые возникают при получении неподходящих данных или работы в неподходящем окружении (например программа пробует читать из файла, которого может не оказаться). Такие ошибки можно обрабатывать посредством нагромождения `if` и кодов возвратов (С-style), однако исключения могут работать эффективнее, как в плане скорости получаемого кода, так и в плане его упрощения.

Comment: И, кстати, исключения — это не ошибки программирования, если уж на то пошло...

Comment: @Acinit, извиняюсь, увидела сообщение только после написания своего.

Спасибо за ответ

Comment: @Harry, это исключение появлялось в программе курсовой, что я делала. И в зависимости от проблемы я давала ему разные значения. Признаю, что пример взят от балды, но Acinit уже дал ссылку на схожий вопрос, пойду разбираться в нем

Спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Из документации Microsoft learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/exception-handling-statements)

> Операторы `throw` и `try` используются для работы с исключениями. Используйте оператор `throw`, чтобы создать исключение. Используйте инструкцию для перехвата `try` и обработки исключений, которые могут возникнуть во время выполнения блока кода.

Когда возникает критическая или неожиданная ситуация, программа может сгенерировать исключение с помощью оператора `throw`. Это позволяет **передать управление к месту, где исключение будет обработано**.

Оператор `throw` принимает в качестве аргумента объект-исключение, который может быть любым типом, но обычно это класс, производный от базового класса `std::exception`. Объект-исключение содержит информацию о типе ошибки или необычной ситуации.

Исключение может быть перехвачено и обработано с помощью блока `try-catch`. Блок `try` содержит код, который может вызвать исключение, а блок `catch` содержит код, который обрабатывает исключение. Если в блоке `try` возникает исключение, выполнение кода в этом блоке прерывается, и выполнение переходит в соответствующий блок `catch`, соответствующий типу исключения.

В общем говоря, практика отлова ошибок позволяет повысить устойчивость программы от непредвиденных обстоятельств. Создание собственных ошибок - буквально вклад в будущее, читая огромный модуль, в котором есть ошибка, мы можем сразу понять в каком месте она была вызвана, чтобы начать анализировать конкретно это место.

Answer (score 1):

Что-бы чутка въехать в разного рода исключения, можно рассмотреть к примеру такой код. Где разные условия исключений создают разное поведение программы.

При этом исключения в отличии от флагов, тебе позволяют их отлавливать на разных уровнях приложения. Не только внутри тела одной функции но и раздельно по классам. К примеру если отвалился SQL в базу, то всё в порядке просто грохаем сам запрос. А если отвалилось всё соединение с базой то это совсем другой разговор. Там надо принимать кардинальные меры и перезапускать соединение по новой.

```
// Online C++ compiler to run C++ program online
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

class ThisWillStopOnlyLocal: public std::exception {
public:
    char const * what() const noexcept override {
        return "Custom C++ Exception";
    }
};

class ThisWillStopAll: public std::exception {
public:
    char const * what() const noexcept override {
        return "Custom C++ Exception";
    }
};

int main() {
    int input;
    try {
        try {
            std::cout << "Input 1, 2 or other number: ";
            std::cin >> input;
            switch (input) {
            case 1: throw ThisWillStopOnlyLocal{};
            case 2: throw ThisWillStopAll{};
            }
            std::cout << "everything fine" << std::endl;
        } catch (ThisWillStopOnlyLocal const & e) {
            std::cout << "only subrequest dead" << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "step 2 will continue" << std::endl;
    } catch (ThisWillStopAll const & e) {
        std::cout << "everything was dead" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```